# XML file not updated by DataSet object

Tags: xml, datagridview, dataset

When I'm adding a new row, the DataSet are not applies the changes of the DataGridView.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace DataXML
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataSet ds = new DataSet("Database");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!File.Exists("Database.xml"))
                CreateXMLFile();

            ds.ReadXml("Database.xml");

            DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
            dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table"];
            dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            dgv.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(CellValueChanged);
            Controls.Add(dgv);
        }

        private void CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ds.GetXml());
            ds.WriteXml("Database.xml");
        }

        private void CreateXMLFile()
        {
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table"))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
                dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
                dt.Columns.Add("Column3");
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            }

            using (XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter("Database.xml", null))
            {
                XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
                xd.LoadXml(ds.GetXml());
                xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                xd.Save(xtw);
                xtw.Close();
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this happens, just create new "Windows Form Application" and paste this code to test it.

Every time you will change the cell's value the message box with the new XML content, but sometimes (and I still don't know when exactly) the content are not changed by DataSet to XML file, so the DataGridView will not save the last changes if I will close the program.

This is my problem:

[image: Image of my problem]

Comment: Try : ds.AcceptChanges();

Comment: @jdweng I tried all this (and still don't works)
DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
dgv.Refresh();
dgv.Update();
ds.GetChanges();
ds.AcceptChanges();
ds.Tables["Table"].GetChanges();
ds.Tables["Table"].AcceptChanges();